# Creating a plugin on qpy which counts attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a qpy plugin and I am getting an error. The part of the code I have added is below.

```
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()

    layers=self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list=[]
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())

    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)

    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result==1:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        index=self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
        layer=self.dlg.comboBox.itemData(index)
        QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Hello world","%s has %d features."%(layer.name(),layer.featureCount()))
```

Error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You haven't really defined the variable `layer` apart from in the for loop. So the current value of `layer` will be whatever the last value it was when itterating through that loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly, thank you!

Comment: No worries, if you found my comment useful, please mark it as useful :)